# Does first or second place matter in Euro 2016 Qualification?

Tags: football, euro, qualifying

When qualifying for the Euro 2016 competition, the first 2 placed teams of a qualification group automatically qualify.

Does the place in the group have any impact to the tournament draw or seeding?

Ie, will the team that places first in their qualification group get drawn against more favourable teams, than the team that qualified in second?

Or is the draw based on the ranking of the teams, independent of the qualifcation process?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The place in the group does not have any impact on the draw or seeding.

The are four pots in the draw for UEFA Euro 2016 and teams are divided into pots according to the National Team Coefficient:

[image]

For more information read article:

[UEFA EURO 2016 final tournament draw details](http://www.uefa.com/uefaeuro-finals/draws/round=2000448/index.html)